# VueJS 2 - Listen to event in mixin

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm currently trying to create a mixin for Vue which basically creates a property passthrough chain. I'll clarify what should happen to be a little more clear;

Let's say I got 3 components; A,B and C.

A & B are both the same component called 'content-pane' (See below for template code).

```
    <div class="pane-wrapper">
        <div class="content-pane" :class="{'is-hidden' : !active}" :content="name">
            <div class="card white">
                <div class="card-title grey darken-3">
                    <h1 class="white-text">{{ label }}</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="card-content white">
                    <component
                        :is           = "type"
                        :routes       = "routes"
                        :passthrough  = "passthrough"

                        keep-alive
                    ></component>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <content-pane
                v-for="(pane, key) in children"

                :key        = "key"
                :label      = "pane.label"
                :name       = "pane.name"
                :active     = "true"
                :type       = "pane.type"
                :routes     = "pane.routes"
        ></content-pane>
    </div>
```

C is a dynamic component, meaning that it is interchangeable and could be any component.

Now I want to be able to access certain data from component C in component A, and for that I am trying to create a mixin that dyamically offers a data property to do this:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'passthrough',

    props: {
        passthrough : {
            type    : Object
        }
    },

    data ()
    {
        return {
            // This object allows you to
            // update the parent.
            passthroughModifier : {
                // We use the data object inside the
                // original object because Vue doesn't
                // want to detect direct prop changes
                // when they are added dynamically
                // into the root object...
                data : {}
            }
        }
    },

    methods : {
        /**
         * This function fires an emit event.
         */
        emitUpdate ()
        {
            this.$emit('passthrough-update', this.passthroughModifier);
        }
    },

    watch : {
        /**
         * Emit an event once the passthrough
         * property has been changed.
         * We need to use a deep watcher.
         */
        'passthroughModifier' : {
            handler : function (val) {
                this.emitUpdate();
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },

    created ()
    {
        // Allow access to the instance
        // inside the iteration.
        let _that = this;

        // Attach a listener for the passthrough update
        // which will walk through all the keys in the
        // data object and hard-set these locally.
        this.$on('passthrough-update', function (data) {
            Object.keys(data).forEach(function (index) {
                _that.passthroughModifier[index] = data[index];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except listening to the 'passthrough-update' event, which is fired by the watcher on $.passthroughModifier.

So; When component C updates its $.passthroughModifier.data, the event gets emitted, but component B isn't able to catch this event.

I have tried to listen for this event in the `created()` method of the mixin (see code above), but it seems as if the event only gets caught in the component the event is fired from. So component C fires the event, and component C listens to its own event.

I hope someone is able to tell me wether this is actually possible or not, and what I'm doing wrong if it is possible.

Comment: What is the parent-child relationship of components A, B, and C?